# Setting cookie in PHP, then redirecting to new URL and access the set cookie?

Tags: php, facebook, cookies, redirect, wufoo

Im trying to set a cookie, then redirect to a new URL and access( or check if the cookie is set) the set cookie, but it doesn't seem to be available in the new URL.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.facebook.com/pages/tabappURL");
setcookie('coupon', true, time() + 120); //hold for 2 min, time in seconds
?>
```

Any ideas?

Also, let me explain what is, or why Im trying to do this.  I have a Facebook tab app, which is an iframe... A user likes the page, then is presented with a contest entry form (powered by Wufoo). Once the user submits the form, wufoo redirects to a thank you page... though, it refreshes and takes you away from Facebook. This wasnt the ideal situation since we want the thank you page to reside within the iframe.  I had no control of targeting the iframe on wufoos end so the work around would be to redirect to another page on my server (same server that is hosting the content in the iframe) set a cookie, then redirect back to the FB app page.  Then the FB app checks if the cookie is set, then displays the thank you message.

Technically this is two pages:

index.php (which has)

```
<div class="not-liked">please like us</div>
<div class="liked">enter contest</div>
<div class="thanks">thank you</div> <!-- hidden until page refresh and cookie set -->
```

redirect.php (which has the cookie/redirect code above)

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are typically only accessible within a specified domain.

From the PHP documentation:

> **domain**: The domain that the cookie is available to. To make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com (including example.com itself) then you'd set it to '.example.com'. Although some browsers will accept cookies without the initial ., » RFC 2109 requires it to be included. Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' or '.www.example.com' will make the cookie only available in the www subdomain.

Comment: This resides in an iframe Facebook app, so the the content Im pulling in is from the domain the cookie was set it.

Comment: Is the PHP code actually loading/executing from a facebook server? or are you hosting that script elsewhere? Facebook.com may be issuing the iframe, but if the contents's coming from your server, your server will be considered the origin point for the cookie and WON'T be available to facebook-hosted pages.

Comment: everything is taking place withing an iframe, it is all hosted on my server.

Comment: How can it all be hosted on your server? You are redirecting to Facebook's domain.

Comment: everything inside of the iframe is hosted on my server/domain.  All of Facebooks tab apps are now iframe driven.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser settings to see if you have enabled third-party cookies. In some browsers, if they are disabled a page inside an iframe will not receive cookies even if they belong to the same domain.

Comment: what's the point in answering a question already answered a year ago?

Comment: A year ago?! I think you read the dates wrong. And although it is a month old, it was not yet answered in a way that solved the problem for the OP.

Comment: his problem has nothing to do with browsers

Answer (score -1):

Did you call session_start()? That will get PHP to check the request headers for the session cookie.

Comment: yes, this was suggested in some other threads.. I tried this, but no luck.